# Recommended time to finish a cup of coffee for the best caffeine surge?

Tags: caffeine

Is there such thing as a recommended time lapse in which to finish drinking a cup of coffee, in which you get the best kick out of the caffeine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physiologically, as soon as substances enter the body, they are being processed, entering your system and subsequently removed from it. By that logic, you will experience the greatest net effect of the caffeine content of your cup of coffee by finishing it in the shortest amount of time possible. This is assuming that your definition of 'best kick' is indeed attempting to feel the most potent effects of the caffeine available in your cup.

Comment: Cool. I guess more of what I mean is, how can I maximize the amount of time and effects of a cup of coffee. Sort of like feeling an average kick of caffeine and making the cup of coffee last the longest possible amount of time, while still having an average effect of it's caffeine in the human body.

Comment: It's almost nigh impossible to tell since everyone's caffeine tolerance is different and thus you cannot even relate caffeine dosage to it's felt effects on each individual. This question doesn't actually have any useful one-answer-fits-all. All I can say is, to ensure a stable ride through the caffeine, you'll need to be drinking it in uniform mouthfuls, with uniform intervals for a stable caffeine intake. The sizes of the mouthfuls and intervals are the variables that are dependent on the individual and therefore the time taken will also be variable if we assume an 8oz cup.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope I that was helpful!

Comment: Thank you! It very much did!